# Using Symfony Validation component to validate specific array structure depending on key inside the given array

Tags: php, symfony

Given the following array:

```
$a = [
    ['type' => 'foo', 'abc' => 'whatever'],
    ['type' => 'bar', 'xyz' => 'whatever'],
];
```

I would like to use Symfony Validation component to validate `$a`. `$a` should be of type array, and each of the elements inside it should be arrays and should conform to one of two rules:

- if key `"type"` of the element is `"foo"`, then key `"abc"` is required
- if key `"type"` of the element is `"bar"`, then key `"xyz"` is required

I was trying to use the `All` constraint together with `Collection` constraint to specify fields, but that didn't do the job since it basically forced me to make both `"abc"` and `"xyz"` optional.

How would one go about validating this?

Comment: Use `Assert\Callback` and write your own validation function. Or create a custom validator.

Comment: you can cehck symfony expression. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html#basic-usage

Comment: did you checked this documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score -1):

Which version of symfony are you using ?

I would suggest you to create your own validation constraint to complete the task.

To do so, you'll need to create and extends two classes.

- A `Constraint` that that will be use for naming the constraint and use it.
- A `ConstraintValidator` that will perform the validation.

Both classes should be in the same namespace.

An example of the **Constraint** could be:

```
namespace FooBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ArrayStructure extends Constraint
{
    public $message = "The array structure is invalid";
}
```

N.B. The "message" property will be used in the validator to show an error message.*

The **ConstraintValidator** could be:

```
namespace FooBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class ArrayStructureValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($array, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof ArrayStructure) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, ArrayStructure::class);
        }

        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $reqired = null;
            switch ($element['type']) {
                case 'foo':
                    $reqired = "abc";
                case 'bar':
                    $reqired = "xyz";
            }

            if ($reqired) {
                if (array_key_exists($reqired, $element)) {
                    $this->context
                        ->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                        ->addViolation()
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

N.B. The class name **must** be the same as the Constraint + "Validator"*

You can use the custom Validation Constraint you create specifying its use in the form in the field (s) you want, like:

```
// ...
use FooBundle\Validator\Constraints\ArrayStructure;

class FooBarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("array", BarType::class, [
                "constraints" => [new ArrayStructure ()]
            ])
        // ...
    }
}
```

For complete reference go to this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/custom_constraint.html) .

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22824953)

Comment: Thanks for the directives, i'll edit this answer and produce a better quality version

Comment: I'm not using the form component though, but the same principle can be applied here anyway. Thanks!